# Display a text like a book content

Tags: css, sass

I would like to design a content where it's text will divide into two columns. Please refer below image get better idea. It should automatically adjust it's size as data is dynamic.

[image]

You are help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have so far?

Comment: @khan I am amateur in css. So I don't have any idea about it. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my code pen. Hope this will help you.
Add column gap and width -

```
column-width: 14em;
column-gap: 2em;
```

As expample -

```
<div class="conatiner">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu. A diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra. Vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. 
</div>
```

And css -

```
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  column-width: 14em;
  column-gap: 2em;
  column-rule: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Check working [example](https://codepen.io/abhishekhonrao/pen/bGVbWmK)